Permanently and forcefully banish OneDrive for all users in Windows 11 via powershell
First, a bunch of background:
I'm working on prepping about 20 laptops for an educational program in a prison. This environment has some... special challenges. One of these is students (prisoners) are not permitted under any circumstances to have anything even marginally resembling email or electronic messaging access.
This means they cannot have Microsoft Accounts at all and will not have access to an AD domain or Entra Identity; only local accounts will do (and removing the MS Account nags will be a separate question), and group policy/system center/intune/other MDM management is off the table.
It also means they cannot have One Drive anywhere on the computer. If a student were to manage to get One Drive open and connected, they could use it to create a shared folder to someone outside the prison and exchange messages by dropping in text files.
Yes, we really have to be that careful, and finding out after the fact we failed to get this right involves the kind of penalties I don't want to think about.
It further does not matter the OneDrive service will be blocked on the prison network. The machines will be inspected before delivery, and my understanding talking to other organizations that finding One Drive will cause them to fail inspection.
An additional aspect of the situation is there is no real on-site tech support. My current understanding (which could still be wrong) is the education coordinator in the prison is given a local admin account and detailed instructions on how to open Computer Management and create a new local user with a distinct password for each student (also known to the coordinator). So I need this to work as the default experience for new users.
Again, I have a batch of these, with the potential need to add more on the horizon. I do know I always start from a fresh/clean Windows installation, and right now they are all the same make/model. But I also know it's doubtful the next batch will be the same brand, so I can't count on the systems looking exactly the same. This isn't the only weird/extra thing I need to do for these machines, so I would really like this to be scripted, such that the process will be repeatable.
In short (too late), I'm highly motivated to ensure OneDrive really is totally gone from these systems in a repeatable way; it's likely I'll even have the final script run nightly as a scheduled task, to protect against accidental re-install. It really does need to be for all users, including users not yet created, and it's more than just the usual, "Boo hoo, I don't like OneDrive, why do I have to put up with it?" whining.
So far I have this:
# Make sure OneDrive isn't later changed to be a Windows Store app
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers "*OneDrive*" | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers

# But really OneDrive uses any of five possible locations:
# Windows\System, Windows\System32, Windows\SysWOW64, Program Files, and Program Files (x86)
# Need to check all five
if (Test-Path "C:\Windows\System\OneDriveSetup.exe") {
    start -wait -filepath "C:\Windows\System\OneDriveSetup.exe" -argumentlist "/uninstall","/qn"
}
if (Test-Path "C:\Windows\System32\OneDriveSetup.exe") {
    start -wait -filepath "C:\Windows\System32\OneDriveSetup.exe" -argumentlist "/uninstall","/qn"
}
if (Test-Path "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\OneDriveSetup.exe") {
    start -wait -filepath "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\OneDriveSetup.exe" -argumentlist "/uninstall","/qn"
}

# Program Files locations also have a version number subfolder that may change over time
if (Test-path "C:\Program Files\Microsoft OneDrive") {
    $folder = (get-childitem "C:\Program Files\Microsoft OneDrive").Name | ?{ $_ -match "^\d{2}.*" }
    # can be several folders. Only one will have the uninstaller
    $folder | % {
        if (Test-Path "C:\Program Files\Microsoft OneDrive\$_\OneDriveSetup.exe") {
           $path = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft OneDrive\$_\OneDriveSetup.exe"
            start -wait -filepath $path -argumentlist "/uninstall","/qn"
        }
    }
}
if (Test-path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft OneDrive") {
    $folder = (get-childitem "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft OneDrive").Name | ?{ $_ -match "^\d{2}.*" }
    # can be several folders. Only one will have the uninstaller
    $folder | % {
        if (Test-Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft OneDrive\$_\OneDriveSetup.exe") {
           $path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft OneDrive\$_\OneDriveSetup.exe"
            start -wait -filepath $path -argumentlist "/uninstall","/qn"
        }
    }
}

# Also look in WinSXS
$ods = get-childitem "C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-onedrive-setup*"
if ($ods) {
    $path = "C:\Windows\WinSxS\$($ods.Name)\*.*"
    # Don't need to uninstall; just remove files. But also need to take ownership first
    takeown /F $path /A | Out-Null
    icacls $path /grant Administrators:M | Out-Null
    remove-item -path $path -force
}

I include this script to show what is already done, and not because I need any help with code (and this is why I'm here at Super User instead of on Stack Overflow).
I further have the ability elsewhere in my script to easily add changes to the default user profile registry hive and local machine:
reg load HKU\default c:\users\default\ntuser.dat
reg import .\DefaultRegistryFixes.reg
reg unload HKU\default

The result is anything in that DefaultRegistryFixes.reg file can reference HKEY_USERS\default and it will be written into the registry settings given to new users. The file currently has about 40 registry edits. Nothing there yet has anything to do with OneDrive, as I really need OneDrive to be fully removed, and not just disabled. However, anything I can do here to also disable OneDrive is good, since I want additionally protect against a system update putting OneDrive back on the computer, and if a registry change is the only way to stop it running for a new user I am prepared.

And now, finally, my problem:
After all this, I see OneDrive is gone from the initial admin account I use to run the script. But if I then create a new local user and login, I see One Drive running in the system tray. Task Manager shows the .exe file is living in that user's (brand new) App Data folder.
What am I missing, that One Drive is still running on the system when I add a new user, even after removing it from these other locations? And how can I remove it finally once and for good?

It sounds like you want to disable internet access. Because even if you disable the OneDrive client, it will not prevent anyone from going to portal.office.com or live.com, login there and use the webclient for either email or onedrive. You don't need a client to share files, but you do need internet access. Restrict internet access, and you've solved every single contingency. If internet access is necessary, use something like a proxy server, and limit which sites can be visited, excluding live.com and office.com

You can use this process to also remove OneDrive. I am not going to try to analysis your script since I know it won't work to remove OneDrive on Windows 10+. The Microsoft account issue can be similar resolved here. Why Windows 11?

@LPChip No, we definitely want to allow internet access. We're working with the prison to get our self-hosted canvas instance exempted from their firewall, with appropriate settings in Canvas to prevent it's use as a messaging tool for talking to anyone but the course instructor, so students can use it to access course material and submit assignments.

Once you do the EU trick to allow applications like Edge and OneDrive to be removed, this explains how to remove OneDrive, instead of using the script, which I suppose could be used to remove it from WinSxS but blocking Windows Store from being launch would be a better solution.

@Ramhound Oh, we also have to block Windows Store launch ;) We need Windows 11, because we're still required for the machine to get Windows Update security patches after October of next year, when Windows 10 will be end of life.

So, if you want to allow internet access, and you don't prevent access to onedrive.com, office.com, live.com, etc... anyone can use OneDrive from the web version, which allows anyone to login, and download/upload files and share that way. If these domains are blocked from the internet, the OneDrive client, even when installed, will automatically fail. Also, don't forget that the same is possible for other sharing services, such as dropbox, google drive, etc... Not to mention, every webmail.

@LPChip That part is up to the prison's firewall. We have to ensure the software does not exist on the computer. Yes, yes, I know, it's silly. But that's government for you.

To put it another way: this requirement is actually enshrined in state law, where it uses the word "application". The law was enacted back when the internet was new and web email clients were not really considered. The result is it's a felony to provide an application enabling two-way electronic messaging between a prisoner and any person outside the prison, even by accident and whether it works or not. I aim to be compliant with state law, especially when jail time is involved.

I had a similar delema with my school district. One thing we did was setup Linux (Debian) as opposed to Windows. We could then force a proxy setting for every user to run through one "router" computer with an allow list of sites allowed to be visited. I highly recommend this option if you're willing to learn a bit of Linux.

I know linux pretty well. But it's not a good fit for the prison environment.

Would a fresh install be an option?  https://github.com/ntdevlabs/tiny11builder/tree/main might be a good starting point , Might need some tweaking to not remove things you need, and I think it bypasses the unsupported hardware stuff, but that strips down a windows system to the bare essentials

This IS a fresh install. But tools like Tiny11 tend to be too aggressive, and leave unexpected things broken.

I now have things so I believe OneDrive is fully removed using a script and reg file. The script:
Write-Host "Removing OneDrive"

# First make our registry tweaks. To do this, we need the default user's hive loaded
reg load HKU\default c:\users\default\ntuser.dat

# Now, before importing changes, look for the OneDrive Personal installer location (we'll need it later) 
#  Also, KHU isn't available by default, so check that, too
if ((Get-PSDrive -PSProvider Registry).Name -notcontains 'HKU') {
    New-PSDrive HKU Registry HKEY_USERS | Out-Null
    $removeHKU = $true
}
$odp = (Get-ItemProperty -path 'HKU:\default\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run').OneDriveSetup
if ($removeHKU) {
    Remove-PSDrive -Name "HKU"
}

# Import our registry changes
# This removes the command to install OneDrive again from the default user template
reg import .\DefaultRegistryFixes.reg
reg unload HKU\default
# Done with registry

# Make sure OneDrive isn't later changed to be a Windows Store app
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers "*OneDrive*" | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers

# OneDrive is installed in one or more of five possible locations:
# Windows\System, Windows\System32, Windows\SysWOW64, Program Files, and Program Files (x86)
# Need to check all five

# First, the Windows locations
if (Test-Path "C:\Windows\System\OneDriveSetup.exe") {
    start -wait -filepath "C:\Windows\System\OneDriveSetup.exe" -argumentlist "/uninstall","/qn"
}
if (Test-Path "C:\Windows\System32\OneDriveSetup.exe") {
    start -wait -filepath "C:\Windows\System32\OneDriveSetup.exe" -argumentlist "/uninstall","/qn"
}
if (Test-Path "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\OneDriveSetup.exe") {
    start -wait -filepath "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\OneDriveSetup.exe" -argumentlist "/uninstall","/qn"
}

# Then Program Files. 
# These locations also have a version number subfolder that may change over time
# So we need extra steps to find that folder
if (Test-path "C:\Program Files\Microsoft OneDrive") {
    $folder = (get-childitem "C:\Program Files\Microsoft OneDrive").Name | ?{ $_ -match "^\d{2}.*" }
    # can be several folders. Only one will have the uninstaller
    $folder | % {
        if (Test-Path "C:\Program Files\Microsoft OneDrive\$_\OneDriveSetup.exe") {
            $path = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft OneDrive\$_\OneDriveSetup.exe"
            start -wait -filepath $path -argumentlist "/uninstall","/qn"
        }
    }
}
if (Test-path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft OneDrive") {
    $folder = (get-childitem "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft OneDrive").Name | ?{ $_ -match "^\d{2}.*" }
    # can be several folders. Only one will have the uninstaller
    $folder | % {
        if (Test-Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft OneDrive\$_\OneDriveSetup.exe") {
            $path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft OneDrive\$_\OneDriveSetup.exe"
            start -wait -filepath $path -argumentlist "/uninstall","/qn"
        }
    }
}

# Now look in WinSXS for the setup file backup
$ods = get-childitem "C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-onedrive-setup*"
if ($ods) {
    $path = "C:\Windows\WinSxS\$($ods.Name)\*.*"
    # Don't need to uninstall. Just remove the files. But also need to take ownership first
    takeown /F $path /A | Out-Null
    icacls $path /grant Administrators:M | Out-Null
    remove-item -path $path -force | out-null
}

#   And finally clean up installer program found earlier in the registry
if ($odp)
{
    $odp = $odp.Replace(" /thfirstsetup", "") # remove command line argument
    takeown /F $odp /A | Out-Null
    icacls $odp /grant Administrators:M | Out-Null
    remove-item $odp | out-null
}

The registry file:
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00


[HKEY_USERS\default\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run]
"OneDriveSetup"=-

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run]
"OneDriveSetup"=-
"OneDrive"=-

Remember, script has loaded the default user hive specially for this .reg file to be effective.
This successfully removes OneDrive from a new system, and I no longer see it running after creating a new user. If there are other users on the system already created, still more work will be needed. But that's not my situation at this time.

But I'm not done.
I expect the above script will be effective for a month or three, but then a Windows Update will eventually patch the installer and default registry. This isn't even Microsoft trying too hard to push their own products. It's just a natural result of the servicing platform doing it's thing, either after patching a CVE or when a new version is available as part of an annual feature update.
So, to prevent OneDrive from coming back, this code (and some other things) will also be included as a recurring scheduled task. Then, when OneDrive eventually comes back it will just get pulled again. That should stop it appearing for new users, which is a rarer event. I'm also looking into additional registry tweaks I can use to make it less aggressive during the potential period of up to about a day where it may exist on a system, so it doesn't end up installed in a user's AppData folder.
As another measure, I'm considering changing the script code to write placeholder files over top of the existing OneDriveSetup.exe files, with custom access control lists that do not permit write access to SYSTEM or TRUSTED INSTALLER principals. But I'm worried this would break and force rollbacks for larger Updates, leaving systems in an unsecured state, and so that's not in the current plan.
Finally, we may also make manual security policy tweaks on each system, to block the installers from running. But since I haven't seen a way to make that scriptable/repeatable, I'm saving it as a last resort.

I’ll mention this again, if you add your region to this, once removed OneDrive won’t return.

@Ramhound my understanding is that only works if you have a EU region. I don't, and I'm not willing to configure it for the wrong region, as that has undesirable side effects.

Did you read the information I provided? You modify a single file, add your region to the file, and change the permission to a single file that likely will never change. Your response suggests you didn't read the answer I had provided or any the information.
